# unable to detect empty for Sequence using map function in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to check if method returns empty

```
val test: Option[Seq[Employee]] = repo.findByName(name);
print(test)
test.map(r => print(r.seq)).getOrElse(print("not found"))
```

The return type of my function `repo.findByName` (calls database to check if name exists) is `Option[Seq[Employee]]`

Output

```
Some(Buffer())
Some(Buffer())
```

I expect the output - **not found**

Comment: It seems like `findByName` returns an empty sequence if it doesn't find a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for emptiness of the `Option[T]` in case the return type is an *empty sequence* (as it seems like that's what the API is returning), you can do:

```
val result: String = repo
               .findByName(name)
               .filter(_.nonEmpty)
               .fold("no employees")(_ => "found employees")
println(result)
```

If you want to print out employees, you can do:

```
val result: Seq[Employee] = repo
                             .findByName(name)
                             .getOrElse(Seq.empty[Employee])

result.foreach(println)
```

Will print out each employee, assuming it's a case class and has a proper `toString`.

Comment: I need to print values of object Employee and not the text

Comment: You can use `fold` to print whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`test.map(r=>if(r.isEmpty) "it's empty" else "not empty").getOrElse("something else")`.

It's likely that None in this case doesn't mean it was not found but rather some error occured, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
print(test.map(r => r.seq).getOrElse(Seq("not found")))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use an `Option`, ensure that it will return a `Some` or `None`.

It seems from your example that `findByName` will always return a Some.

Anyway, if you must work with that, then this should return something useful:

```
test.getOrElse(Nil) match {
      case Nil     => println("Not Found")
      case x :: xs => println(x :: xs)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val result = repo.findByName(name)
                 .filter(_.nonEmpty)
                 .map(_.toString)
                 .getOrElse("not found")

print(result)
```

`result` is a `String` and is assigned the value `"not found"` if `repo` returns `None` or a `Some[Seq[Employee]]` in which the `Seq[Employee]` is empty.